# Create App-Specific folder in External Storage in Android Q

Tags: android, android-api-levels

I want to create an app-specific folder in Internal Storage similar to Whatsapp, Telegram, etc. Apps whose target SDK is 29, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory` has been deprecated. Now, Android does allow to create such a folder using legacy flags, but I want to know is there any other way to do so.

I want to create a folder at this path - `/storage/emulated/0/MY_APP`. `MY_APP`is name of my folder I want to create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know is there any other way to do so

No. And, on Android 11+, once your `targetSdkVersion` reaches 30, you will not be able to use `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`. Note that this should also affect the apps that you cite, except perhaps those that are pre-loaded by device manufacturers.

What Google wants is for you to use the Storage Access Framework and let the *user* decide where on the *user's* device the *user's* app (i.e., you) should place the *user's* content, rather than you deciding for them.